# Error about "type signature with no binding"

Tags: haskell

I have a problem with ASCII in Haskell.

```
fromEnum :: Char -> Int
toEnum :: Int -> Char

offset :: Int
offset = fromEnum 'A' - fromEnum 'a'

toUpper :: Char -> Char
toUpper ch = toEnum (fromEnum ch + offset)
```

This script gives an error:

```
The type signature 'fromEnum' lacks an accompanying binding
The type signature must be given where 'fromEnum is declared

The type signature 'toEnum' lacks an accompanying binding
The type signature must be given where 'toEnum is declared
```

Comment: You can't write a type signature for a function that you didn't define yourself.  (Both `fromEnum` and `toEnum` are from the `Prelude` module.)

Comment: Side note: Haskell `Char`s are not ASCII!

Answer (score 3):

`fromEnum` and `toEnum` are standart functions

please try this:

```
offset :: Int
offset = fromEnum 'A' - fromEnum 'a'

toUpper :: Char -> Char
toUpper ch = toEnum (fromEnum ch + offset)
```

Comment: @user4394101, Please check my answer as useful :)

Answer (score 3):

Unless you are doing this as an exercise, you should really use `toUpper` from module `Data.Char`.

Doing this well requires to check how uppercase is defined in Unicode -- I'd rather rely on the standard library for that :)

Also, watch out because your `toUpper` is not idempotent: one might expect that `toUpper 'A' == 'A'`, for instance.